# "Natürlisch", oder nur "natürlich"?

Tags: spelling, adverb

I've just detected a misspelled "natürlich" — written like "natürlisch". Is it a mistake or slang/dialect?

Comment: It can be both. In standard German, it's `natürlich`, but in some dialects and sociolects it's spoken like `natürlisch`, which may also be written like that if one wants to emphasize this way of speaking it.

Comment: It is not common in German to write in dialect. Only in special literature, jokes or to express the special dialect. But it is really seldom. So without any given context I would guess it is wrong spelled. By the way the dialect where "natürlisch" might be used would be Thuringian or Saxon.

Comment: Please add more context to your question, where did you detect the misspelling, what is the complete sentence? Otherwise your question might get closed not being detailed enough or too broad.

Comment: I'm analysing room search requests (from a linguistic perspective) written by males and females on wg-gesucht.de.

Comment: So, one person used "natürlisch" to answer the question about her/his free time ("FIFA natürlisch!")

Comment: Drunk people often pronounce *ch* as *sch*. That's used to indicate *an urge to party*, too.

Comment: Also there is a growing group of residents in Germany who seem to cultivate a sociolect in which "ch" principally is pronounced like "sch". These are mostly people with cultural roots in what once was called the Near Orient. I say "seem to cultivate" because I do not know if they are aware of this or if they just habitually are not able to discern the phones behind ch and sch, like for Germans it is usually difficult to differenciate v and w in English.

Answer (score 3):

If somebody writes “natürlisch” in a phrase like *“FIFA natürlisch!”* it's virtually certain that it was done intentionally.

It's such a common word that it is not likely to be spelled wrong by genuine mistake.

On the other hand the context let's you expect such kind of jokes. It's common to spell “natürlich” formally incorrect as “natürlisch” to hint at certain sociolects or even just to emulate the slurred speech of drunk people.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from a comment:

It can be both. In standard German, it's *natürlich*, but in some dialects and sociolects it is pronounced *natürlisch*. It may also be spelled like that if one wants to reproduce this pronunciation in writing.